# Can quantifiers expand into any implication?

Tags: logic, boolean-logic, quantifiers

In the statement:

```
(∀x)(A→(B→C))
```

can the universal quantifier be distributed using an axiom such that the result would be:

```
(∀x)A→(∀x)(B→C)
```

then applying the axiom again to make:

```
(∀x)A→(∀x)B→(∀x)C
```

Assuming `A→(B→C)` and `A→B` to be true, how would you prove `A→C`

Comment: Can you describe (or give a reference) to the logic you're using. What is A, B and C ? Where appears x ? etc. On the wikipedia page of boolean algebra for instance, there is no use of quantifiers, so what is the difference between the logic you're using and boolean algebra ?

Maybe it is just a matter of naming, so can you just describe more what you want to do ?

Comment: A, B, and C can be translated as P(x), Q(x) and R(x). For the sake of the question, they are referred to as A, B and C. I am trying to prove that given (∀x)(P(x) → (Q(x)→R(x)), and (∀x)(P(x)→Q(x)), they prove (∀x)(P(x)→R(x))

Answer (score 2):

The universal quantifier cannot be distributed. Here is why

```
 ∀x: A(x) → B(x)            "every time A is true, so is B"
(∀x: A(x)) → (∀x: B(x))     "if A is always true, B is always true"
```

The first implies the second but the second doesn't imply the first. For instance

```
(∀x: x is odd) → (∀x: x is even)
```

is `true` because `x` is not always odd and not always even (and `false → false` is `true`). However

```
∀x: (x is odd → x is even)
```

is clearly `false`.